# Inserir em dois banco de dados php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Quero inserir dados de um cadastro em dois banco de dados ao mesmo tempo  usando PHP/MYSQL.

Há alguma possibilidade? .

Só estou conseguindo com uma conexão, quando faço o require de duas conexões nada acontece!

Preciso de um exemplo de código amigos

Answer (score 4):

Se for no mesmo servidor:

```
$con = mysqli_connect( 'end.do.servidor', 'usuario', 'senha ' );

if( !$con ) die( 'Falha na conexao: '.mysqli_connect_error( $con ) );

$sql1 = 'INSERT INTO nomedobanco1.tabela1 (....)';
$sql2 = 'INSERT INTO nomedobanco2.tabela2 (....)';

if( mysqli_query( $con, $sql1 ) ) echo 'Inserção 1 OK' else die( mysqli_error( $con ) ); 
if( mysqli_query( $con, $sql2 ) ) echo 'Inserção 2 OK' else die( mysqli_error( $con ) );
```

Se forem servidores diferentes:

```
$con1 = mysqli_connect( 'end.do.servidor1', 'usuario', 'senha ' );
$con2 = mysqli_connect( 'end.do.servidor2', 'usuario', 'senha ' );

if( !$con1 ) die( 'Falha na conexao 1: '.mysqli_connect_error( $con1 ) );
if( !$con2 ) die( 'Falha na conexao 2: '.mysqli_connect_error( $con2 ) );

$sql1 = 'INSERT INTO nomedobanco1.tabela1 (....)';
$sql2 = 'INSERT INTO nomedobanco2.tabela2 (....)';

if( mysqli_query( $con1, $sql1 ) ) echo 'Inserção 1 OK' else die( mysqli_error($con1 ) );
if( mysqli_query( $con2, $sql2 ) ) echo 'Inserção 2 OK' else die( mysqli_error($con2 ) );
```

Para PDO, a lógica é a mesma, basta adaptar a sintaxe.

Se estiver usando uma conexão só, e um *engine* como InnoDB, pode usar um `BEGIN TRANSACTION` antes dos 2 `INSERT`s e um `COMMIT` em seguida, para garantir que a transação só seja efetivada se tudo correr bem nas duas inserções, evitando que apenas uma tabela seja modificada. Se estiver usando duas conexões, precisa pensar em outra solução para garantir a consistência.

Comment: Vou verificar aqui amigo, desde já agradeço

Comment: é possivel ter varias conexões da banco de dados usando este exemplo

Comment: usando um require ou include?

Comment: Require e include não influenciam em nada no banco de dados, são apenas funções para organização do código. Para o PHP é praticamente indiferente se está tudo em um código só ou se foi incluído. O número de conexões independe disso também, pode estar em include, função separada, classe, etc..

Comment: então Bacco posso inserir aqui no meu aquivo de conexão.php e alimentar meus dois banco de dados sem problema né?

Comment: Como você não deu detalhes na pergunta, me ative ao problema das conexões. Não tem problema nenhum por várias conexões no include. O que precisa prestar atenção é no caso de falhar uma só das inserções, você precisa tratar isso na lógica da sua aplicação (leia o que escrevi sobre transactions). Quanto a colocar as conexões no include, sem problema nenhum. Inclusive, se forem sempre os mesmos nomes de tabela, você pode criar uma função que já insira em todas, em vez de ficar repetindo código. Foge um pouco do que foi perguntado, mas é bom você depois de testar tudo direitinho, pensar na idéia.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgfus.png

Comment: deu um erro estranho

Comment: Provavelmente por não ter usado a sintaxe indicada na resposta. Você está passando uma string onde deveria ser a conexão.

Comment: O Bacco está corretíssimo, é só duplicar a conexão alterando o nome e os dados dela(server, base, user, psw...), depois você faz dois inserts um com a conn1 na tabela x e outro com a conn2 na tabela y, usando os mesmos dados já obtidos no PHP.